# How to find an element within a frame in IE?

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, iframe, iedriverserver

Code trials:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'path')]")));
driver.findElement(By.id());
```

Switching to Frame is **may be** successful but it didn't throw any NoSuchFrameException.

The same is working in Chrome and FireFox. But the same is not Working in IE (tried in IE9 and IE11).
WebDriver Used: IEDriverServer Ver: `3.12.0.0`

Is it because of the Document mode? or due to any Page rendering issue? 
In What Case will this happen?

`HTML` Source Code Link: [Source Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rOaQmxTugwTIzhm9QF9vGkCfaTPaXLmz/view?usp=sharing)

Tried to Find the id `MF:txtentdon`

I don't know if this is important or not, but It also throws `HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'stale element reference' (400 expected)`

Error Stack Trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #MF\:txtentdon
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'N9776', ip: '172.29.18.139', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{proxy=Proxy(), acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=9, se:ieOptions={nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0.0, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0.0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:6017/, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000.0, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false}, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, browserName=internet explorer, pageLoadStrategy=normal, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows, setWindowRect=true, platform=ANY}]
Session ID: 48da0488-5d2e-46db-996e-77f27f26ff28
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=MF:txtentdon}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:410)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:453)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:402)
```

Comment: what xpath are you using ? update the question with xpath . try with different locators

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB I have updated with error stack trace.

Comment: @cruisepandey I have updated what xpath I used. And I have tried locators (id, cssSelector)

Comment: @cruisepandey One is input id and other is input name. Both have same value

Comment: My doubt is, why does **findElement(By.id("MF:txtentdon"))** returns Unable to find element with **css selector** == #MF\:txtentdon..

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #MF\:txtentdon
```

...implies that the **InternetExplorerDriver** server was unable to locate the desired element.

Your main issue seems to be the **incompatibility** between the *version of the binaries* you are using as follows:

- You are using **Selenium Java Client v3.4.0**
- You are using **IEDriverServer v3.12.0.0**
- You are using **JDK v1.8.0_131**

So there is a clear mismatch between *JDK v1.8.0-131*, *Selenium Client v3.4.0* and *IEDriverServer v3.12.0.0*.

### Solution

While you work with *Selenium Java Client*, *InternetExplorerDriver* and *Internet Explorer Browser* ensure that:

- You have fulfilled the [**Required Configuration**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration) as well as the additional considerations for [**Native Events**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#native-events-and-internet-explorer) and [**Browser Focus**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#browser-focus) as per the documentation of [**InternetExplorerDriver**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver).
- You have upgraded *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u171**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
- You have upgraded *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.12.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- You have upgraded *InternetExplorerDriver* to  current [**IEDriverServer v3.12.0**](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html) level.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

A couple of additional facts you need to consider while switching frame to locate element:

- Always induce *WebDriverwait* while switching to desired *frame*.
- Once you switch to the desired *frame* induce *WebDriverwait* while you look out for the desired element.
- As your desired element is having the attribute **readOnly="readonly"** so you need to use the *ExpectedConditions* as [`visibilityOfElementLocated()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) as follows:
- So your effective code block will be:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'path')]")));
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@class='inputfld' and @id='MF:txtentdon']")));
  ```

Comment: I have tried this one and I got the below error: 
` org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //input[@class='inputfld' and @id='MF:txtentdon'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:232)
 
 Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //input[@class='inputfld' and @id='MF:txtentdon']`

Comment: I don't know if this is important or not, but It also throws                   `INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'stale element reference' (400 expected)`

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps you need to cross check your _IEDriverServer_ configuration

Comment: I have already mentioned that I am using IE9 and IEDriverServer Version 3.12.0. Protected Mode is Enabled and Zoom Level is set to 100%. Any other configuration to be checked?

Comment: Even though it didn't throw `NoSuchFrameException` , I have a doubt whether it actually switched or not.

Comment: @Ray Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status,

Comment: I have done as you said, Still It couldn't find the element. Forget the element, I couldn't even print the iframes which are inside the **target iframe** using `List<WebElement> afterswitch = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));` after switching to the iframe, but it prints the iframes before the **target iframe**

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code :

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'path')]")));  
System.err.println("inside frame");
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("MF:txtentdon")));
```

**Or**

```
WebElement element =  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("MF:txtentdon")));
```

Comment: `inside frame
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.name: MF:txtentdon (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)`

Comment: Is URL public ?

Comment: No. It's not public

Comment: @Ray : are you facing stale element reference ?

Comment: Actually I am getting an INFO below `INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'stale element reference' (400 expected)`